# how to get the value from json in android

Tags: json

Hi am getting the following json pentaho server,How i need to get date from this json

```
"queryInfo":{
    "totalRows":"1"
},
"resultset":[
    [
        "09-09-2014"
    ]
],
"metadata":[
    {
        "colIndex":0,
        "colType":"String",
        "colName":"dt"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use gson to deserilize the string:
Create a Class in a separate file.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class pentaho {

    public QueryInfo queryInfo;

    public static class QueryInfo {
        public List<Result> metadata;

        public static class Result {
            @SerializedName("colIndex")
            public String colIndexStr;

            @SerializedName("colType")
            public String colTypeStr;

            @SerializedName("colName")
            public String colNameStr;
        }

    }
 }
```

In your Activity

```
      public pentaho pentahoResult;
```

In your functions.

```
private void getJson(String jsonStr){
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  pentahoResult = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, pentaho.class);
```

Now you can go through each result if there is more than one by replacing the 0 with a loop variable like int i.

```
String MycolIndex = pentahoResult.d.results.get(0).colIndexStr;
String MycolType = pentahoResult.d.results.get(0).colTypeStr;
String MycolName = pentahoResult.d.results.get(0).colNameStr;
```

Have fun.